# Targeting Multiple Dynamically Created Elements in one function

Tags: jquery

I've got the following event which delete a given li element from a dynamically created list. However because of certain presentation features that I'm running I've now also got another list called "date-and-time-options-for-alert-box" which contains a duplicate of the same li element (with the same ID name) which I also need to remove when someone clicks the delete button, however I'm unable to achieve this.

At the moment I'm trying to target the li element in question using, but have tried a whole bunch of different things...

```
$('#date-and-time-options-for-alert-box', $(this).attr("href")).remove();
```

The rest of the code if as follows, and works as expected. Would really appreciate some guidance here.

```
$(document).on('click', '#delete', function(e) {
    $($(this).attr("href")).remove();

    $('#date-and-time-options-for-alert-box', $(this).attr("href")).remove();//THIS DOESN'T WORK!       

    $($(this).attr("href")).remove();

    numberOfOptions = numberOfOptions - 1;

    if(numberOfOptions < 1){
        $( "#submit-date-time-options" ).hide( "fast" );            
    }

});
```

Comment: ID of an element must be unique... can you share the html also

Comment: `$('#date-and-time-options-for-alert-box', $(this).attr("href")).remove();` does not seems to be right... because in that line you are trying to delete a descendant element... but since you are removing `$(this).attr("href")` itself it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Arun P Johny, of course an ID has to be unique, I made it unique and modified the code as follows and it did the trick:

```
var IDToRemove = $(this).attr("href");

        alert(IDToRemove);


        $(IDToRemove).remove();
        $(IDToRemove+'_alert_box').remove();
```